# Авторизация на сайте используя requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

**Сама проблема - мне нужно переписать код программы указанной ниже на python(не всю программу а только код логина с помощью requests на сайт https://vega.ua/)**
Итак есть программа AnyBalance на андройд на которую ставятся пакеты которые как сообщает программа работают на java.
Вот сам пакет http://anybalance.ru/catalog/ab-telephony-vegatele/
В файле main.js сам код логина и парсинга сайта https://vega.ua/ но почему то прописанный как https://my.vegatele.com/
Я находил ответы как залогиниться на сайт с помощью requests но единственный рабочий ответ который я нашел это https://stackoverflow.com/a/61140905/12045924
Но мне нужна полная автоматика потому этот ответ не подходит.

**Повторяя проблему - нужен код на питоне который бы заходил на сайт и только.**
Также есть ещё один вопрос - в файле *main.js* есть строки 49-53 getParam которые как раз и получают значения с сайта. Мне нужно понять как получить значение на изображении. Строку с новой ссылкой на страницу я могу записать а вот как правильно написать строку получения значения не могу.[image: нужное значение]

Ну и сам код на питоне который я успел написать но который не хочет заходить(headers использую которые дал выше приведённый ответ)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

g_headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
}

login = requests.get('https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login', headers=g_headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(login.text, features="lxml")                                            
for n in soup('input'):                                                        
    if n['name'] == '_csrf':                                             
        token = n['value']                                                     
        break  

header = {
    'referer':'https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login',
    'X-CSRF-Token':token,
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}

html = requests.post('https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login', {
        'login':'login',
        'password':'password',
    }, headers=header)

html = requests.get('https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login', headers=g_headers)

print(html.text)
```

P.S. Извиняюсь если это был не *java* а *java script*

Comment: Лучше в вопросе предоставить всю информацию. Например, вы пытались переписать на питон код с другого языка, тот код нужно предоставить в сам вопрос, т.к. вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, к тому же это повысит шансы получить ответ (мне лично лень переходить по ссылкам и там что-то качать) :)

Answer (score 1):

POST запрос на `https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login` вернулся с `200 Ok`, вместо  `403 Forbidden`.

Пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login'

session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'

rs = session.get(url)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

name_by_value = dict()
for input_el in root.select('#vega_auth_login input[name]'):
    name = input_el['name']
    name_by_value[name] = input_el.get('value', '')

name_by_value['login'] = '1111'
name_by_value['password'] = '2222'

auth_data = {
    f'vega_auth_login[{name}]': value
    for name, value in name_by_value.items()
}

session.headers.update({
    'X-CSRF-Token': name_by_value['_csrf'],
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
})

rs = session.post(url, files=auth_data)
print(rs)
# <Response [200]>
```

#### А чтобы получить `200` сделал следующее:

Посмотрел в браузере на запрос авторизации и увидел расхождение.

1. В запросе отправляется и `_csrf`, т.к. он присутствует на форме в виде `input`.
2. В запросе каждое поле из `input` оборачивается в `vega_auth_login[<поле>]`, т.е. не `login`, а `vega_auth_login[login]` (у той формы `id='vega_auth_login'`, наверное, такое правило оборачивания названий полей):
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В запросе `Content-Type` будет `multipart/form-data`, а у вас получится `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, т.к. `{'login':'login', 'password':'password',}` попадет в параметр `data`, а [для того запроса нужно будет передавать в `files`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/5909792):

   ```
   # Тут перечислить поля
   login_data = {
       ...
   }
   html = requests.post('https://my.vegatele.com/ru/auth/login', files=login_data, headers=header)
   ```
4. Для понимания того какие данные отправляются `requests`, [советую включить ему отладку](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/47b5b4ff084ab8b173118bd4c1aa6425517d7366/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L17):

   ```
   # These two lines enable debugging at httplib level (requests->urllib3->http.client)
   # You will see the REQUEST, including HEADERS and DATA, and RESPONSE with HEADERS but without DATA.
   # The only thing missing will be the response.body which is not logged.
   try:
       import http.client as http_client
   except ImportError:
       # Python 2
       import httplib as http_client
   http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

   # You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
   import logging
   logging.basicConfig()
   logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
   requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   requests_log.propagate = True


   import requests
   ...
   ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ но... я все равно не могу зайти) я добавил print(rs.text) и вывело все тот же текст об авторизации.  Что -бы я понимал что я всё правильно настроил - это всё что нужно настроить - name_by_value['login'] = '1111'
name_by_value['password'] = '2222'

Comment: @Arhangel, вы попробовали выполнить мой код, указав настоящие данные и сайт все-равно не пропустил? Не уверен, что добавив только поля логина и пароля, сайт может пропустить, скорее всего ему еще и _csrf добавить, и возможно, еще другие поля (в моем коде они все собираются в запрос, `print(name_by_value)`). Плюс, данные для запроса нужно передавать в параметр `files`, чтобы был правильный `Content-Type` и данные были правильно сформированы перед отправкой (смотрите пункт 4, чтобы отлаживать на своей стороне запрос)

Comment: @Arhangel, кст, если мой ответ был полезным, то не забудьте [проголосовать за него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Спасибо что напрявляете меня но к сожалению я не смогу понять как это сделать. Могли бы ли вы кинуть полный код логина? сам код поиска csrf я показал выше если он подходит

Comment: @Arhangel, в моем коде в ответе, вместо 1111 и 2222 в `name_by_value['login'] = '1111'` и `name_by_value['password'] = '2222'`, введите настоящие логин и пароль и попробуйте войти. Если не вышло, то откройте тот сайт, на странице сайта откройте инспектора (F12, как на скриншоте у меня), перейдите на вкладку **сети**. Теперь авторизовывайтесь на сайте, введя логин и пароль, при этом в **сетях** будут показаны запросы на сайт. Имея на руках правильные запросы, добавьте логирование requests (пункт 4) и смотрите что отправилось requests, сравнивания с тем, что было в запросах браузера

Comment: очень извиняюсь что так туплю - я просто не знаю всех тонкостей а потому не могу такого сделать. я не могу понять какие конкретно запросы просматривать а тем более какие параметры брать и как записывать в коде. Если вам не сложно то не могли ли бы вы кинуть полный код?

Comment: @Arhangel, в предыдущем комментарии, прочитайте мое первое предложение там все описано. Следующие предложения это что делать, если не заработало

Comment: да я читал комментарии и ваше решение проблемы. я изменил `name_by_value['login'] = '1111' name_by_value['password'] = '2222'` но я так и не смог зайти. дальнейшее ваше объяснение мне не помогает так как я не знаю какие конкретно запросы брать и что дальше делать с теми параметрами. если у вас будет время то не могли ли бы вы залогиниться с помощью кода? потому как я не смогу такое реализовать